Reference request for matrix inequality
I'm reading Montgomery and Vaughan's "The Large Sieve" (1973), and they cite this standard result:
Lemma: Suppose that $(c_{ij})_{i,j}$ is an arbitrary $R \times C$ matrix, and $A$ is a constant such that
$$
\sum_{j = 1}^C \left|\sum_{i = 1}^R c_{ij}v_i\right|^2 \leq A\sum_{i = 1}^R |v_i|^2
$$
for all sets of complex numbers $v_i$. Then,
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^R \left|\sum_{j = 1}^C c_{ij} w_j\right|^2 \leq A\sum_{j = 1}^C |w_n|^2
$$
for all sets of complex numbers $w_j$.
However, it seems the citation in the text is incorrect, as I cannot find the lemma in the [8] "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" (at least not at theorem 288), nor in [7] "Inequalities".


This article is available here

In terms of matrices and matrix norms, it basically says that if $|C^T|_2\le A$, then $|C|_2\le A$ (here $|\cdot|_2$ denotes the induced $2$-norm of a matrix). This is because $|C^T|_2=|C|2$. This is obvious if you are familiar with singular value decomposition. Alternatively, one may use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove that $\max{|v|_2=1}|v^TC|2=\max{|v|_2=|w|2=1}|v^TCw|=\max{|w|_2=1}|Cw|_2$.

Seems an awfully complicated way of writing a straightforward result.

@user1551 Ohh I see what you mean now. I haven't come across matrix norms that much before, but comparing the definitions I see how the statement matches what you said. Thanks!

@copper.hat I wasn't familiar with matrix norms before so I didn't recognise the concept here. But thanks!
